# How can I make a table cell stay in its original position when a new cell appears?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I make a `<td>` stay in the center when a new `<td>` is set to `display='block'`. As you can see from the first image, when any radio button is selected, the `components` section is centered. But in the second image, when the last radio button is selected, a new `<td>` appears because then it gets set to `display='block'` and moves the center Components section a little to the left. How do I make it stay in the center?

When all radio buttons are selected:
[image: when all radio buttons are selected]

When only the last radio button is selected:
[image: when only the last radio button is selected]

```
<div>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="standard-table standard-table-mini" summary="Object Table" style="padding-left: 224px; padding-right: 50px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th align="center" style="right-padding:10px;"><b>Action</b></th>
                <th align="left"><b>Components</b></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="even">
                <td align="left">
                    <div class="field">
                        <input type="radio" name="compAction" id="COMP_SHUTDOWN" value="COMP_SHUTDOWN" onclick="controlEquipment(); displayLabel();">
                        Shutdown<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="compAction" id="COMP_RESET" value="COMP_RESET" onclick="controlEquipment(); displayLabel();">
                        Reset<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="compAction" id="COMP_SWITCHOVER" value="COMP_SWITCHOVER" onclick="controlEquipment(); displayLabel();">
                        Switchover<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="compAction" id="COMP_SHORTLOOPCALIBRATION" value="COMP_SHORTLOOPCALIBRATION" onclick="controlEquipment(); displayLabel();">
                        Short-Loop Calibration<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="compAction" id="COMP_RFPATHSWITCH" value="COMP_RFPATHSWITCH" onclick="controlEquipment(); displayLabel();">
                        RF-Path Switch<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="compAction" id="HOTSWAPIN" value="HOTSWAPIN" onclick="controlEquipment(); displayLabel();">
                        Hot-Swap In<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="compAction" id="HOTSWAPOUT" value="HOTSWAPOUT" onclick="controlEquipment(); displayLabel();">
                        Hot-Swap Out<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="compAction" id="COMP_PBSCCNLINK" value="COMP_PBSCCNLINK" onclick="controlEquipment(); displayLabel();">
                        PBSC-CN Link<br>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td align="center" style="padding-right: 60px;">
                    <div class="field">
                        <select multiple="" id="ComponentsId" name="ComponentId" class="dropdown" size="5" style="width: 190px;height:95px;"><//some option value stuff />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td align="right" style="display: block;" id="pbsclabel"> <input type="text" id="seconds" name="seconds" value="30"> <label for="seconds">seconds</label><br>
                    <b>Check results in directory:</b><br> /sdb1/ngpgsftp/PBSC/WIRESHARK/</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Tables are probably not the best layout tool for your particular case, but you could accomplish this by setting specific widths on the `<td>` elements instead of letting the table adjust itself based on its contents.

Comment: @DanielBeck How should I try this by setting specific widths? Could you guide me please?

Comment: Your title row has two cells (`th`), while the next row contains three cells (`td`). That won't work as a table anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted the td size and adjusted it slightly to the right and left. When you add a new td you have to unintentionally allocate some space to it. I set the middle td value higher than the rest so that the change is not noticeable.

```css
.middle-td{
  width:50%;   
}
td,th{
    width:25%;
}
.wrapper
{
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="standard-table standard-table-mini" summary="Object Table" style="padding-left: 20; padding-right: 20px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th align="left" style="right-padding:10px;"><b>Action</b></th>
                <th class="middle-td" align="center"><b>Components</b></th>
                 <th align="left"><b>Components</b></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="even">
                <td align="left">
                    <div class="field">
                        <input type="radio" name="compAction" id="COMP_SHUTDOWN" value="COMP_SHUTDOWN" onclick="controlEquipment(); displayLabel();">
                        Shutdown<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="compAction" id="COMP_RESET" value="COMP_RESET" onclick="controlEquipment(); displayLabel();">
                        Reset<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="compAction" id="COMP_SWITCHOVER" value="COMP_SWITCHOVER" onclick="controlEquipment(); displayLabel();">
                        Switchover<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="compAction" id="COMP_SHORTLOOPCALIBRATION" value="COMP_SHORTLOOPCALIBRATION" onclick="controlEquipment(); displayLabel();">
                        Short-Loop Calibration<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="compAction" id="COMP_RFPATHSWITCH" value="COMP_RFPATHSWITCH" onclick="controlEquipment(); displayLabel();">
                        RF-Path Switch<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="compAction" id="HOTSWAPIN" value="HOTSWAPIN" onclick="controlEquipment(); displayLabel();">
                        Hot-Swap In<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="compAction" id="HOTSWAPOUT" value="HOTSWAPOUT" onclick="controlEquipment(); displayLabel();">
                        Hot-Swap Out<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="compAction" id="COMP_PBSCCNLINK" value="COMP_PBSCCNLINK" onclick="controlEquipment(); displayLabel();">
                        PBSC-CN Link<br>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="middle-td" align="center">
                    <div class="field">
                        <select multiple="" id="ComponentsId" name="ComponentId" class="dropdown" size="5" style="width: 190px;height:95px;margin-top: -60px;"><//some option value stuff />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td align="left" style="display: block;" id="pbsclabel"> <input type="text" id="seconds" name="seconds" value="30"> 
                <label for="seconds">seconds</label><br>
                    Check results in directory:
                    <br>
                    /sdb1/ngpgsftp/PBSC/WIRESHARK/
                    </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Clicking a radio button produces an error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: controlEquipment`

Comment: I do not have a script for it. I only worked on the table style

Comment: Maybe you could add that caveat to your answer, along with a description of your style edits?

Comment: thank you . I added my explanation to the answer

Answer (score 0):

I see three options to complete this and still use tables if that's what you want to do, but I don't recommend any of them. **Look below the list for my recommended option.

1. Use absolute widths for all three columns, ensuring that's the widths keep the middle column at the center.
2. Use the colspan attribute on the second column (both the second `th` and the `td`) to increase their width and then add padding to the left to keep the content looking center.
3. Make the third column `position: absolute` to remove it from the flow altogether.

Those options aside, I believe there are **BETTER** solutions available to use you that would actually accomplish what it is you are trying to do here. Using a more modern CSS technology such as CSS Flexbox or Grid, you can dynamically center content as you need to.

Here's how I would develop it, using CSS Grid and only one lightweight JS event listener to show/hide that last column when needed (try running it to test):

```js
document.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.matches('[name="compAction"]')) {
        const field = e.target;
        const pbsclabel = document.getElementById('pbsclabel');
        if (pbsclabel) pbsclabel.style.display = field.value === "COMP_PBSCCNLINK" ? "block" : "none";
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    padding: 8px;
}
.table-3col {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
    gap: 15px;
    width: 850px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    user-select: none;
}
.table-3col > .col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    text-align: left;
}
.table-3col > .col > .col-inner {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
}
.table-3col > .col:nth-child(1) { align-items: flex-start; }
.table-3col > .col:nth-child(2) { align-items: center; }
.table-3col > .col:nth-child(3) { align-items: flex-end; }
.table-3col > .col strong {
    display: block;
}
.field {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
th, td {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-3col">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="col-inner">
            <strong>Action</strong>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="COMP_SHUTDOWN"><input type="radio" name="compAction" id="COMP_SHUTDOWN" value="COMP_SHUTDOWN"> Shutdown</label>
                <label for="COMP_RESET"><input type="radio" name="compAction" id="COMP_RESET" value="COMP_RESET"> Reset</label>
                <label for="COMP_SWITCHOVER"><input type="radio" name="compAction" id="COMP_SWITCHOVER" value="COMP_SWITCHOVER"> Switchover</label>
                <label for="COMP_SHORTLOOPCALIBRATION"><input type="radio" name="compAction" id="COMP_SHORTLOOPCALIBRATION" value="COMP_SHORTLOOPCALIBRATION"> Short-Loop Calibration</label>
                <label for="COMP_RFPATHSWITCH"><input type="radio" name="compAction" id="COMP_RFPATHSWITCH" value="COMP_RFPATHSWITCH"> RF-Path Switch</label>
                <label for="HOTSWAPIN"><input type="radio" name="compAction" id="HOTSWAPIN" value="HOTSWAPIN"> Hot-Swap In</label>
                <label for="HOTSWAPOUT"><input type="radio" name="compAction" id="HOTSWAPOUT" value="HOTSWAPOUT"> Hot-Swap Out</label>
                <label for="COMP_PBSCCNLINK"><input type="radio" name="compAction" id="COMP_PBSCCNLINK" value="COMP_PBSCCNLINK"> PBSC-CN Link</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="col-inner">
            <strong>Components</strong>
            <div class="field">
                <select multiple="" id="ComponentsId" name="ComponentId" class="dropdown" size="5" style="width: 190px;height:95px;">
                    <option value="1">NGPS00-PBSC3-1</option>
                    <option value="2">NGPS00-PBSC3-2</option>
                    <option value="3">NGPS00-PBSC3-3</option>
                    <option value="4">NGPS00-PBSC3-4</option>
                    <option value="5">NGPS00-PBSC3-5</option>
                    <option value="6">NGPS00-PBSC3-6</option>
                    <option value="7">NGPS00-PBSC3-7</option>
                    <option value="8">NGPS00-PBSC3-8</option>
                    <option value="9">NGPS00-PBSC3-9</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pbsclabel" class="col" style="display: none;">
        <div class="col-inner">
            <strong>&nbsp;</strong>
            <input type="text" id="seconds" name="seconds" value="30"> <label for="seconds">seconds</label><br>
            <strong>Check results in directory:</strong> /sdb1/ngpgsftp/PBSC/WIRESHARK/
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This working solution also provides easy flexibility to collapse the columns down to one column on mobile devices, which is not so easily done with HTML tables.

I hope this helps! I'm happy to answer any follow-up questions you might have.